# I need to create this sine wave in MATLAB. How does one go about it?

Tags: matlab, plot, signal-processing, noise, trigonometry

I was given the original sine wave(**Image 1**) and a noisy version of it too(**Image 2**).

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Now to find the original signal, I am looking at the frequency in the first half of the graph which has the greatest value. This would be 21. When I try to create a sine wave with 21 as a frequency using the code below, I get the result of **Image 3**.

```
% Creating the Sine Wave
t = (1:1:256); 
A = 1; 
y = A*sin(2*pi*max_index*t);

plot(t,y);
```

**Image 3**

[image]

Why is this the case. What am I doing wrong?

---

**RUNNABLE CODE**

Here is my Function:

```
function [  ] = function1b( Sig_noise )

% Max Index is the frequency of the pure tone
noise_f = fft(Sig_noise); 
s_nf = size(noise_f);
size_f = s_nf(2); 
max = 0;
max_index = 1; 
for n = 1:(size_f/2)
    if abs(noise_f(n)) > max 
        max = abs(noise_f(n));
        max_index = n; 
    end
end

% Creating the Sine Wave
t = (1:1:256); 
A = 1; 
y = A*sin(2*pi*max_index*t);

plot(t,y);

end
```

And I am calling it from this part of the script:

```
load('Sig'); % Original Signal
Sig_noise2=awgn(Sig,10);
function1b(Sig_noise2);
```

---

**Andras' Solution**

This is the result I seem to be getting:

[image]

Using `linspace(0,2,100)`; gives me this result:

[image]

Comment: Can you post some runnable code? To me this looks alright, your amplitude should not change, because A is constant, so no idea why you are getting this output.

Comment: @lhcgeneva just made the change!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code says

```
t = (1:1:256); 
A = 1; 
y = A*sin(2*pi*max_index*t);
```

While your amplitude is nice and big and `1`, if `max_index` is integer then your phase inside the `sin` is an integer multiple of `2*pi` for every `t`, which is exactly zero. This is why your function is numerically zero. You need the *frequency* of the max index:

```
y = A*sin(2*pi*freq(max_index)*t);
```

if the frequencies are stored in `freq`, or if `max_index` already stands for a frequency, then use a denser `t` mesh, like

```
t = linspace(1,256,1000);
```

---

You might be misinterpreting the output of `fft`. From `help fft`:

```
 For length N input vector x, the DFT is a length N vector X,
 with elements
                     N
       X(k) =       sum  x(n)*exp(-j*2*pi*(k-1)*(n-1)/N), 1 <= k <= N.
                    n=1

 The inverse DFT (computed by IFFT) is given by
                    N
      x(n) = (1/N) sum  X(k)*exp( j*2*pi*(k-1)*(n-1)/N), 1 <= n <= N.
                   k=1
```

That means that the frequencies are not `max_index`, but `(max_index-1)/N` if your original sample has `N` points. This turns your flawed large frequency into the actual small frequency, solving your issues.

To break it down to you: try

```
t = 1:256;
y = A*sin(2*pi*(max_index-1)/length(Sig_noise)*t);
```

Comment: `Undefined function or variable 'freq'.` is the error I get when I try to change `y = A*sin(2*pi*max_index*t);` to `y = A*sin(2*pi*freq(max_index)*t);` Let me try your second solution.

Comment: I've also modified the question so that it holds more info on how I got the value of `max_index`.

Comment: I've also posted the result of the second solution that you have mentioned.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala the frequency, in your case `max_index` tells you the number of oscillations in 1 time unit. If your `max_index` is equal to 20, then from `t=0` to `t=1` you have 20 oscillations. That's why you see what you're seeing. Try plotting with `t=linspace(0,2,100)`, a much shorter time scale.

Comment: just added what happens if I modify it in that way.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala Sorry, 100 was a bit optimistic. I meant something like `t=linspace(0,1,10000)`. That should be smooth.

Comment: what I need is the same graph as the original signal. What do you mean by `N` points?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala I refuse to believe that you honestly can't understand what I wrote. See my updated answer............

Comment: not sure why I'm getting downvoted on this question. Yes, I understand completely now. I was getting confused because of the tighter and looser meshes produced by linspace. This is certainly the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is some problem in sampling rate. 
replace

```
t=(1:1:256)
```

with

```
t = (1:1/(f*3):3)
```

Here f=max_index =21

Comment: This is certainly giving me the right graph, but not with the right domain. I need it to range till 256 like the original singal?

Comment: You can change domain with t=(1:1/(f*3):256). However, graph won't look as image1 due to low frequency. If you zoom it, then you will see see output as Image 1.

Comment: Yeah, I need the exact same graph as **Image 1**. I seem to be getting a different sinewave with a much higher frequency here.